# Handling misspelled entities

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

let me describe you my problem. I have NLU intent `get_food` with examples like this:

```yaml
version: "2.0"


nlu:
  - intent: get_food
    examples: |
      - I want to know more about [apple](food).
      - I am interested in [pear](food) nutrition facts.
      - Tell me something about [banana](food).
      - ...

  - lookup: food
    examples: |
      - apple
      - banana
      - peach
      - pear
      - avocado
```

The idea is to store extracted entity `food` into slot `food` which is working (almost) as expected. The problem is when a user misspells for example `apple` with `appel`. It's still extracted perfectly but it stores misspelled value `appel` into `food` slot. Is there any way to let my RASA assistant pick exact value listed in look-up table with the highest confidence, store this value into `food` slot and ignore everything not listed in this look-up table? For example if user asks for details about `appel`, it will store `apple` into `food` slot, but if user asks for details about `pineapple` it will store `null` into `food` or something like this. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call a [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/actions/) to clean-up the spelling errors.